# Get the Date where the min max value is at when querying with between

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to get the day when the Min and Max value occurred when querying between certain dates.

Lets say i'm querying between 1st of the month to 31st and i want to see on which day the min and max value for that given column occured.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then col end) as min_val_date,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then col end) as max_val_date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by col asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (order by col desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
      where datecol >= ? and datecol < ?
     ) t;
```

Or you can just use aggregation:

```
select (array_agg(datecol order by col desc limit 1))[ordinal(1)] as max_val_date,
       (array_agg(datecol order by col asc limit 1))[ordinal(1)] as min_val_date
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you, but which would have better performance overhead when querying large data set?

Comment: @Articlaus . . . You might need to check on your data.  I have had good luck with aggregation queries in BQ.

Comment: thank you again, another question if we wanted to include the value along with the date, will it be possible?

Comment: @Articlaus . . . Just add `max()` and `min()` to the queries.  Both have aggregation in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below (if you care of performance)

```
select date_of_min, date_of_max
from (
  select date_col as date_of_min from `project.dataset.table` 
  where date_col between min_date and max_date
  order by value_col limit 1
), (
  select date_col as date_of_max from `project.dataset.table` 
  where date_col between min_date and max_date
  order by value_col desc limit 1
)
```